# Different tiptap editor instances getting synced even with different Y.XmlFragments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tiptap

I am building a project, a collaborative board using yjs & tiptap 2 editor in React.js. I have a board with multiple sections and each section has multiple notes. Each note has its own editor instance with its own fragment. But when I add multiple notes, and type into one, other notes in the same section gets synced with the one I am typing.

Here is my Section component

```
export const Section: React.FC<ISectionProps> = ({ sectionData }) => {
  const sectionHeaderRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const addNoteButtonRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const [maxHeight, setMaxheight] = useState("");
  const [noteListMaxHeight, setNoteListMaxHeight] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sectionHeaderRef.current?.clientHeight);
    setMaxheight(`calc(100% - ${sectionHeaderRef.current?.clientHeight ?? 0}px - 16px)`);
    console.log(maxHeight);
  }, [sectionHeaderRef.current]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(addNoteButtonRef.current?.clientHeight);
    setNoteListMaxHeight(`calc(100% - ${addNoteButtonRef.current?.clientHeight ?? 0}px - 16px)`);
    console.log(maxHeight);
  }, [addNoteButtonRef.current]);

  const prepareNotesJsx = () => {
    return sectionData
      .toArray()
      .map((note, index) => <Note options={{ bodyFragment: note.get("content") }} title={note.get("title")} />);
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-300 max-w-sm rounded-lg p-2 flex flex-col max-h-full" style={{ minWidth: "20rem" }}>
      <SectionHeader ref={sectionHeaderRef} />

      <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow mt-4" style={{ maxHeight }}>
        <DashedButton
          ref={addNoteButtonRef}
          onClick={(e) => {
            const note = new Y.Map();
            note.set("title", "Note");
            note.set("content", new Y.XmlFragment());
            sectionData.insert(0, [note]);
          }}
        >
          <PlusCircleFilled />
          <span className="ml-2 uppercase">Add note</span>
        </DashedButton>

        <div className="flex-grow board-section" style={{ maxHeight: noteListMaxHeight }}>
          <SimpleBar style={{ height: "100%", maxHeight: "100%", marginTop: 8 }}>{prepareNotesJsx()}</SimpleBar>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this is my note

```
const Note: React.FC<INoteProps> = ({ options, title }): JSX.Element => {
  const { provider } = useContext(BoardContext);

  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
      StarterKit.configure({
        history: false,
      }),
      Collaboration.configure({
        // document: ydoc,
        // field: id,
        fragment: options.bodyFragment,
      }),
      CollaborationCursor.configure({
        provider,
        user: {
          name: "user",
          color: "#958DF1",
        },
      }),
      Placeholder.configure({
        placeholder: "Write something...",
      }),
    ],
  });

  return (
    <Card title={title}>
      <EditorContent editor={editor} />
    </Card>
  );
};
```

This is what happens
[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79JvY.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `note.get("content")` returns the same result for each note. I would recommend using the field parameter and passing uuids instead of fragments.